# Can the dual of a finitely-accessible category be accessible?

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories, accessible-categories

What is an example of an accessible category $\mathcal C$ which is not essentially small, such that $\mathcal C^{op}$ is finitely-accessible?

More generally, what is an example of an accessible category $\mathcal C$ (not essentially small) such that one of the following related conditions holds?

- $\mathcal C^{op}$ [continuous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+category) (i.e. $\mathcal C$ has cofiltered limits and the colimit functor $Ind(\mathcal C^{op}) \to \mathcal C^{op}$ has a left adjoint);
- $\mathcal C^{op}$ is [precontinuous](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/11/11/11-11abs.html) (i.e. $\mathcal C$ has colimits and cofiltered limits and the colimit functor $Ind(\mathcal C^{op}) \to \mathcal C^{op}$ preserves limits);
- $\mathcal C$ has finite colimits and cofiltered limits, and they commute;
- $\mathcal C^{op}$ is finitely accessible.

The closest thing to an example I can think of is the category $Hilb$ of Hilbert spaces and contractive maps, which is a self-dual $\aleph_1$-accessible category. But I don't believe that finite limits commute with filtered colimits in $Hilb$.

Comment: I've accepted Ivan's answer, which addresses the title question and hence also the first and last bullet points, but I'd be very interested in seeing more examples.

Comment: I think you've made a slip-up in the last paragraph - $\mathbf{Hilb}$ is $\aleph_1$-accessible, but not locally $\aleph_1$-presentable, nor locally $\kappa$-presentable for any cardinal $\kappa$, on account of the fact that it is self-dual and not a preorder.

Comment: @RobertFurber Thanks, fixed! That was a particularly pernicious error since the theorem you're referring to -- the fact that a category $C$ and its opposite can't both be locally presentable unless $C$ is a preorder -- is in some sense the big obstruction that the whole question is dancing around!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Accessible Categories: The Foundations of Categorical Model Theory** by *Makkai and Paré*, there is the example of a finitely accessible self-dual category. Apparently the example is due to *Isbell*. This is the category of **sets and partial monomorphisms**. The example appears **right after Prop. 3.4.4** and right before 3.4.5.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I've [been through this one before](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2015/04/five_quickies.html#c048961), too -- should have remembered!

Comment: @TimCampion, I relate so much to that. I keep rediscovering stuff I know since forever every day. Is it too early to complain about getting old?

Comment: "So that as Plato had an imagination, that all knowledge was but remembrance; so Solomon giveth his sentence: that all novelty is but oblivion."

Answer (score 3):

Any locally presentable category where epimorphisms are stable under $\lambda$-codirected limits is equivalent to a complete lattice (see http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/10/33-10.pdf, 3.10).

Comment: Thanks! So in particular, that means that the opposite of a locally presentable category can never be precontinuous, giving a negative answer to the second bullet point.